# Using Difference from Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to set a new state for my react project and I'm stuck on what I'm doing wrong.I want to get the difference of 2 integer arrays

```
  const results = _.difference(items, currSelection);
  this.setState({ selected: results });
```

currSelection is:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 7]
```

item is:

```
 [1]
```

when I console.log results, I always get

```
[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the arguments as shown below:

```
const currSelection = [1, 2, 3, 7];
const items = [1];
const results = _.difference(currSelection, items);

console.log(results); //[2, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.difference(array, [values])`

> Creates an array of array values not included in the other given arrays >using SameValueZero for equality comparisons. The order of result values >is determined by the order they occur in the first array.

Arguments

> `array` (Array): The array to inspect.
>
> `[values]` (...Array): The values to exclude.

Returns

> `(Array)`: Returns the new array of filtered values.

Comment: Is this answer somehow different from a comment advising the OP to read the docs? What did the OP do wrong? How can he fix it?